# Connect via Bluetooth with Delphi XE7 using portable printer

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to communicate with a **Sewoo LK-P32** printer via Bluetooth. For this, I am using **Delphi XE7**. I made a few examples that come with Delphi and am not having success. I put the paired printer on tablet and even then I am not able to print continuously.

When I print something have to restart the application, so I can print something again. Below my sources.

Could someone help me? Support on this issue? My time is short to try other technologies.

Method that initiates communication with the printer

```
procedure TForm2.ButtonClickStart(Sender: TObject);
var
  Msg, Texto: string;
  I, B: Integer;
  BluetoothAdapter: TBluetoothAdapter;
  ListaDeAparelhosPareados: TBluetoothDeviceList;
  LServices: TBluetoothServiceList;
begin
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Ponto 1');
    FBluetoothManager := TBluetoothManager.Current;
    if FBluetoothManager = nil then
      Memo1.Lines.Add('FBluetoothManager esta nulo');

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Ponto 2');
    BluetoothAdapter := FBluetoothManager.CurrentAdapter;
    if BluetoothAdapter = nil then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('BluetoothAdapter esta nulo');

    ListaDeAparelhosPareados := BluetoothAdapter.PairedDevices;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Ponto 3');
    if ListaDeAparelhosPareados = nil then
      Memo1.Lines.Add('ListaDeAparelhosPareados esta nulo');

    for I := 0 to ListaDeAparelhosPareados.Count - 1 do
    begin
      LDevice := ListaDeAparelhosPareados[I] as TBluetoothDevice;
      if LDevice.IsPaired then
      begin
        LServices := LDevice.GetServices;
        for B := 0 to LServices.Count - 1 do
        begin
          ServiceGUI := GUIDToString(LServices[B].UUID);
          Guid := LServices[B].UUID;
          ServiceName := LServices[B].Name;
          Memo1.Lines.Add(LServices[B].Name + ' --> ' + ServiceGUI);
          Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  except
   on E: Exception do
   begin
     Msg := E.Message;
     Memo1.Lines.Add('Erro ao Conectar na Impressora: ' + Msg);
     Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
   end;
 end;
end;
```

The method that sends the text to the printer

```
procedure TForm2.ButtonClickSendText(Sender: TObject);
var
  FSocket: TBluetoothSocket;
  ToSend: TBytes;
  Msg, Texto: String;
begin
  try
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Aparelho pareado:' + BoolToStr(LDevice.IsPaired));

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Dados do Guid:' + GUIDToString(Guid));
    FSocket := LDevice.CreateClientSocket(Guid, true);
    if FSocket = nil then
    Memo1.Lines.Add('FSocket nulo');

    Memo1.Lines.Add('Criou Bluetooth Cliente.');
    Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
    if FSocket <> nil then
    begin
      // FSocket.Connect;
      FSocket.Connect;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Criou socket cliente com o ServerSocket');
      Texto := #27 + '|cA' + 'Teste' + #13#10;
      ToSend := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Texto);
      FSocket.SendData(ToSend);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Enviou ' + Texto + ' para a impressora.');
    end
    else
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add('FSocket nulo.');
    end;

  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Msg := E.Message;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('Erro ao Conectar na Impressora: ' + Msg);
      Memo1.GoToTextEnd;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are probably missing `FSocket.Close` call after you are done sending data.

Comment: Dalija, I will test here closing the socket and speak to you. thank you.

Comment: I even closing the socket is giving the following error in Android: java.io.IOException: read failed, closed or socket might timeout, read ret: -1

Comment: Sorry, I cannot test it myself. It looks like when you close the socket it is still communicating with printer.

Comment: Right. Do you have any idea how can I fix this? Do you think with Delphi XE7 is possible? In the example that came in the printer for Android and iOS native ran smoothly, so I need to make it work in Delphi XE7.

Answer (score 1):

I recreated your program, and i get the same problem, but changing your code, it's working fine for me now.

The problem is here

```
if FSocket <> nil then
begin
  // FSocket.Connect;
  FSocket.Connect;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Criou socket cliente com o ServerSocket');
  Texto := #27 + '|cA' + 'Teste' + #13#10;
  ToSend := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Texto);
  FSocket.SendData(ToSend);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Enviou ' + Texto + ' para a impressora.');
end
```

First, i recommend to add Fsocket as a private property, and create ONLY ONE fsocket object. So, your code will changed to

```
if (Assigned(LDevice)) And (Assigned(FSocket))
then Begin
     if Not FSocket.Connected
     then FSocket.Connect
     End
Else Begin
     FSocket := LDevice.CreateClientSocket(Guid, True);
     Memo1.Lines.Add('Device Socked created to '+LDevice.DeviceName);
     FSocket.Connect;
     End;
```

After connected, you can call a TTimer to send what you want, o create a method checking if Fsocket is connected.

```
if Assigned(FSocket)
then Begin
     if FSocket.Connected
     then Begin
          Texto := #27 + '|cA' + 'Teste' + #13#10;
          ToSend := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Texto);
          FSocket.SendData(ToSend);

          Sleep(100);
          End;
     End;
```

Also, you can add a sleep between 2 commands, to be sure the data are received and executed by your printer.

In my case i used an Arduino width Bluetooth hc-06 module.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you keep assigning to `lDevice`.  If there is a second unpaired device then `lDevice` is pointing to that.  You need top `Exit` once you have detected that it is paired.

Also, I personally don't like raising exceptions deliberately.  If a class instance is nil then you should exit,  nolt drill down into it..

For instance

```
if FBluetoothManager = nil then
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('FBluetoothManager esta nulo');
  Exit;
end;
```